# Amazon Kindle desktop application not displaying equations properly

Tags: windows-10, kindle

I have a couple of ebooks which are purchased and downloaded from the kindle store. These are engineering books so they're filled with equations. The issue I have, and have had for half a year is with the amazon kindle desktop app  ( V 1.25.1 last update on 1/4/2019) (my pc is running win10) is that the equations are displayed very small relative text size. And changing the font size, type or page alignment doesn't impact the equations hence it does not correct this. See example
[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UawI.png) .
The update(s) did not fix this. I reported the issue a couple of month ago.

The app doesn't have a zoom in option, so I've been using the windows magnifier app to read the book, but it is quiet cumbersome that way. And the magnifier doesn't correct the text blur caused by enlarging [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbGQc.png)

I did research and there is [this](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=159180), but it is only addressing importing pdf's onto the kindle app. Not the authentically downloaded content.

My question is, if there is a way to fix this myself? 
 I do not know what is causing this issue. And surprised it is not mentioned on the web or corrected by update, unless i'm not searching the correct words?

Any resources would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the publisher needs to fix this. They encoded the book into the Kindle format incorrectly.

Kindle eBooks, especially when purchased, like lots of digital content, include Digital Rights Management (DRM) which prevents unauthorized acts upon the content, including modification of the content.

So you should start by notifying the publisher, either via their Kindle store, or if they have an alternate contact. Inform them of the issue and see what they'll do. It may be possible to report the content to Amazon as well, as it is in their store, and see if they will contact the publisher using their own channels.